# pygame.surface type error: an integer is required

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am new to pygame and i wanted to know what is wrong and how can i fix it, thank you! also my pygame closes right when i open it, thats why i took a screenshot like this one. if you could also explain why it closes that fast, that would be great! (pygame 1.9.2 python 3.4.1 , windows 8)![enter image description here][1]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Primer juego de Gian Di Julio')
mainclock= pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

#positioning the ship into the middle of the screen
ship = pygame.image.load('ship.png')
ship_top = screen.get_height() - ship.get_height()
ship_left = screen.get_width()/2 - ship.get_width()/2

pygame.Surface(ship,(ship_left,ship_top))


while True:
     screen.fill((0,0,0))
     x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     screen.blit(ship, (x-ship.get.width()/2, ship_top))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked it up in the pygame docs:

Surface((width, height), flags=0, Surface) -> Surface

But the returned surface is not used in your program so you might leave it out.

When using pygame.display.flip() there is no need for calling pygame.display.update().

Additionally it should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

It closes quickly because you have a syntax error in your code.

```
pygame.Surface(ship,(ship_left,ship_top))
```

This line tries to create a surface, with dimensions taken from the ship variable.
Since ship is a surface loaded from an image, it fails.

Removing this line will fix the issue.